# GWT, passing an ArrayList to JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

In my GWT application I have a javascript function wich require an array of array as argument. I get the data using RPC, so I get a List< List > from my database. I need this because I have to fill a kind of tree view. For example, I get this from my RPC call: {"A", "A1", "A2"}, {"B", "B1"}, and I have to pass this to my javascript function: [["A", "A1", "A2"], ["B", "B1"]]. In my interface I want to show:

```
A+
  A1
  A2
B+
  B1
```

How can I pass it to my javascript function using JSNI?

Comment: Why do you need JSNI? Can't you do it in GWT?

Comment: Yes, I think we could do it in GWT but we have to use that javascript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live without DevMode (because you use SuperDevMode for instance), Java arrays are the same as `JsArray*` in production mode, so `String[][]` is the same as `JsArray<JsArrayString>`.
In DevMode, there's `JsArrayUtils` which can help (makes a copy in DevMode, returns as-is in production mode, with no overhead), but not for nested arrays (and actually not even for arrays of strings), so not in your case.

If you need/want either lists rather than arrays, or DevMode support, then you'll have to copy the data into a `JsArray<JsArrayString>`.

If you can use arrays but need DevMode support, you can use `GWT.isScript()` to make a specific code branch: make a copy into a `JsArray<JsArrayString>` in DevMode, pass the array as-is in prod mode (that also means 2 JSNI methods, for `JsArray<JsArrayString>` and `String[][]`)

Comment: Do you know how the type signature looks like? `Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayNumber;` is a `JsArrayNumber` but how to write a `JsArray<JsArrayNumber>`?

Comment: Because Java generics work by type erasure, the generic type arguments are not encoded.

Comment: Thanks, I got it then over night [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701465/jsni-jsarrayjsarraynumber-type-signature?noredirect=1#comment24042845_16701465). :)