# JSNI: JsArray<JsArrayNumber> type signature

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

My JavaScript code gives me an array of arrays of `float` values:

```
var serverData = new Array();
var fArray = new Array();
// .. calc mx and my here
fArray.push(mx);
fArray.push(my);
this.serverData.push(fArray);

var out = window.letServerWork(this.serverData);
```

which I want to work with on the server. `this.serverData` will look something like this:

```
{ 

0:  0: 1.123
    1: 1.459

1:  0: 0.543
    1: 1.679

2:  0: 1.157
    1: 0.987
}
```

Therefore I need to know the right signature for this call. This here:

```
  public static native void exportDoLinearRegression() /*-{ 
        $wnd.letServerWork = $entry(@ew.server.algorithm.LinearRegression::doLinearRegression(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JsArray<Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayNumber;>;));
  }-*/;
```

is wrong, but it should look something like this. Does anybody know how the signature has to look like so that this works?

Thank you!

Comment: And what is the Java signature of `LinearRegression.doLinearRegression`? Can you share that method?

Comment: I did add the information, that it's an array of arrays of float values. The parameter of `LinearRegression.doLinearRegression` could be something like `List<float[]>` or something similar. But neither I know how to encode this in "type signatures", nor I know which types would be acceptable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that it's not necessary to tell about the generic type. The GWT compiler is happy if it knows that there will be a `JsArray`. The Java function then defines the generic type. This is how it worked for me:

```
  public static String doLinearRegression(JsArray<JsArrayNumber> points) {

    for(int i = 0; i < points.length(); i++) {
      System.out.println(points.get(i).get(0) + " " +  points.get(i).get(1));
      // do stuff
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static native void exportDoLinearRegression() /*-{ 
        $wnd.letServerWork = $entry(@ew.server.algorithm.LinearRegression::doLinearRegression(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JsArray;));
  }-*/;
```